# Mongoose - entering data in 2 collections in single transaction

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create Saas model where the user who signs up creates a `Company`. So when a user registers, my function is supposed to create a `Company` and put the company id in `User` collections reference.

Now, if the user email is already registered, my mongoose schema rejects that entry. I can't create a `User` first because `Company` id is a required field to create a `User`.

What I need to do is create these two documents in different collections atomically. If `User` save fails, I want to abort that transaction so that it removes the `Company` data too.

Here's my code:

```
const mSession = await mongoose.startSession();
mSession.startTransaction();
try{        
    var company=new Company({
        name: companyName,
        website: companyWebsite
    });

    company= await company.save();

    this.company= mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company._id);
    this.emailVerificationCode = Random.alphanumeric();
    let user = await this.save();
    await mSession.commitTransaction();
    console.log("User on success:", user);
    return user;
}catch(err){
    await mSession.abortTransaction();
    return false;
}finally{
    mSession.endSession();
}
```

In this, `abortTransaction()` does not seem to work as the `Company` data persists anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, if the user email is already registered, my mongoose schema rejects that entry. I can't create a User first because Company id is a required field to create a User.

You can create a **User** first and set its user.comp_id to a locally generated ObjectId:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var company_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

var user = new User({
    comp_id: company_id
});
```

If the email is okay and the **User** is properly saved, you can then create your **Company** with its *_id* being set to the locally generated ObjectId *company_id* that was generated beforehand:

```
var company = new Company({
    _id = company_id,
    name: companyName,
    website: companyWebsite
});
```